# iOS - memory issue with AVAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, avasset

My app is like Vine or Instagram, which records small clips and joins them together. I have problem with memory management when creating avasset.
If I created 100 AVAsset objects from the beginning, it is working fine. But if I keep deleting some of them, and even all of them, and create new ones again, I receive memory warning and also reponds to memory pressure. I check my running app with Instrument and there is no leaked memory.
Below is how I create and remove AVAsset objects in array assets. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

```
- (void) copyFileToDocuments:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/output_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:fileURL toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath] error:&error]) {
    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManager:didFailWithError:)]) {
        [[self delegate] captureManager:self didFailWithError:error];
    }
}

    //add asset into the array or pieces
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath]];
    [self.assets addObject:asset];
}

-(void) deleteLastAsset
{
    AVAsset *asset = [self.assets lastObject];

    [self.delegate removeTimeFromDuration:CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)];

    NSURL *fileURL = nil;
    if ([asset isKindOfClass:AVURLAsset.class])
    {
        AVURLAsset *urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
        fileURL = urlAsset.URL;
    }

    if (fileURL)
        [self removeFile:fileURL];

    [self.assets removeLastObject];
}

- (void) startRecording
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
        [self setBackgroundRecordingID:[[UIApplication sharedApplication]         beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{}]];
    }
    [self removeFile:[[self recorder] outputFileURL]];
    [[self recorder] startRecordingWithOrientation:self.orientation];
}


- (void) removeFile:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
    NSString *filePath = [fileURL path];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] == NO) {
            if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManager:didFailWithError:)]) {
                [[self delegate] captureManager:self didFailWithError:error];
            }            
        }
    }
}


-(void)startRecordingWithOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)videoOrientation;
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [AVCamUtilities connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo         fromConnections:[[self movieFileOutput] connections]];
    if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
        [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];

    [[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self outputFileURL] recordingDelegate:self];
}

-(void)stopRecording
{
    [[self movieFileOutput] stopRecording];
}
```